# Missing FrameworkSampleSource from ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I've been using `ExoPlayer` for the past couple of days until today which when I tried to build the project I found that there is a missing class named `FrameworkSampleSource`.

I tried looking for it in Exoplayer's source but I can not find it anywhere.

It even is gone from [github](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer/FrameworkSampleSource.html)! I wonder what's happened to it?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExoPlayer recently moved away from using Android's `MediaExtractor`, so `FrameworkSampleSource` and `DefaultSampleSource`, as it was named later, were removed from the library. For traditional media playback (not adaptive), `ExtractorSampleSource` can be configured with an `Extractor` like `Mp4Extractor`. There is currently no automatic detection of the media type.

https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#traditional-media-playbacks

Comment: The link was dead, because DefaultSampleSource was removed from ExoPlayer. I've updated my answer.