# Android stream over ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to switch from `MediaPlayer` in favor of `ExoPlayer` but I can't find any updated demo how can I use it.I think they have removed the `FrameworkSampleSource` method. I downloaded the demo from Github but I can't find the implementation of player, I could find the Samples object where the URLs are added.
I have a list of URL's that I want to be played.I am switching to ExoPlayer because it's smoother than MediaPlayer.I have read all StackOverflow topics about ExoPlayer but none of them are updated.

Can anyone give me an example how can implement it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    FrameworkSampleSource source = new FrameworkSampleSource(App.getContext(), track.Uri, null, 1);
    TrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(source, null, true);
    exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
```

Hope this short example will help

Comment: There is no FrameworkSampleSource only FrameworkSampleExtractor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579967/missing-frameworksamplesource-from-exoplayer

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a simple implementation, I've created simple apps from ExoPlayer Demo that are easier to read.

The Link : https://github.com/Gujarats/AndroidVideoPlayer/tree/master/app/src/main

You need to see these files for better understanding :

- Layout : test_player.xml
- TestPlayerActivity
- TestPlayerController

I've tested it and played .mp4 files over HTTP.

Comment: could you tell me how i can use that github in android studio?Thanks

Comment: @user1788736 clone the project, and open android studio, and open the the root folder. the android studio file automatically build the project for you. if not work find the .gralde and open it

Comment: Thanks for reply . You mean i download the github project and open it via android studio?

Comment: I open rooth folder of clone project using android studio and click build and i got following error. Hope you help me fix it . Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 23.0.1 and sync project</a>

Comment: @user1788736 install the Build tools and synch

Answer (score 3):

I had to replace MediaPlayer with ExoPlayer today for a radio streaming app. I made a [post about it](https://irpdevelop.wordpress.com/2016/01/25/exoplayer-add-simple-audio-player-to-android/) in case it would help anyone. 
It uses MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer with ExtractorSampleSource (since FrameworkSampleSource is deprecated).

```
            Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
            String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, "ExoPlayerDemo");
            DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, null, userAgent);
            ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(
                    radioUri, dataSource, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE * BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT);
            audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(
                    sampleSource);

            exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
```